# Injective/Surjective/Bijective question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a constant function $f: \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ given by

ex: $f(x) = 3.14$.

Is a constant, injective, surjective or bijective? I don't know how the mapping works for a constant.

Comment: Could you state the domain and range of the function? If the domain is a single value and the range is a single value then it is all 3. However, depending on what other facts you have for a basis here determines the answer to my mind.

Comment: @JBKing it is just "Determine whether the following is injective, surjective, or bijective"f(x) = 3.14

Comment: How about $f(x) = x?$ can you answer that?

Comment: @John I cannot. But, I can try. It would be injective because x=y, but I'm not sure how to calculate subjectivity.

Comment: Can you also state what is the definition of injective/surjective in our question? Stating precisely the question can help you understand more.

Comment: Injective is mapped one-to-one and surjective is mapped onto

Answer (score 1):

(i) Yes, it is a constant function.

(ii) No, $f$ is not one to one. Consider that $f(1) = f(2) = \cdots = 3.14$.

(iii) No, $f$ is not surjective. Can we find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$?

(iv) Bijective simply means both surjective and injective. Since the function is not surjective, it cannot be bijective.

Comment: if you could take an example codomain (the reals or something) and show that the function isn't surjective, I guess it would make more sense to the OP.

Comment: @shardulc It seems that he has edited his question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following image:

[image: Definition of bijective, injective and surjective functions]

- A function $f(x) = c$ is a constant function if $c$ is a constant. Therefore, it is a constant function with $c = 3.14$.
- For a function to be injective (or one-to-one), the function should never map any distinct pair of elements in domain to the same element in co-domain. Clearly, $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ maps distinct element pairs to same element in co-domain. $ ( \because f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = ... = 3.14)$. Hence, it is not injective.
- For each element in the co-domain of surjective (or onto) functions, there is some element in domain of $f$. Clearly, the element $y = 2.71$ is such that $y \in \mathbb{R}$ ($y$ belongs to the co-domain $\mathbb{R}$). But, there exists no $x$ such that $f(x) = 2.71$  ( or $f(x) = y$). Hence, it is not surjective.
- A function is bijective if it is both injective and surjective. Clearly, it does not meet both the conditions. The function is therefore not bijective.